# Status bar is showing a portion of an image?

Tags: 14.04

I was posting many images on the web for an article. Somehow a portion of an image in now stuck in the Status Bar at the bottom of the screen and I cannot get ride of it.

[image: Status Bar image fragment]

No mouse clicks bring up any menu to get ride of it.
Any ideas on how to clear the image portions?

Comment: does ctrl+alt+<right-arrow> and then back (left-arrow) help (ie. switch to next workspace & back) help ...

Comment: No,it does not.

Comment: sorry I've had that issue happen a number of times, when it does there is something I just instinctively do that clears it. my workspaces usually have more on them than your empty one; I thought because it has to change the apps open for each window causes (bottom) panel to be redrawn that fixed it, either that or is whatever i try next...